# Flutter Firebase Get data from docs and convert map to List?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch data from Firebase and show it.

No data is visible.

There is a problem with the getProduct function. How can I do it?
Please kind answer.

====Build result =========

[image: 1]

===== Model ===

```
class Product {
  String id;
  String name;
  String category;
  String image;
  list images;
  String desc;
  String price;
  Timestamp createdAt;
  Timestamp updatedAt;

  Product();

  Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    id = data['id'];
    name = data['name'];
    category = data['category'];
    image = data['image'];
    images = data['images'];
    desc = data['desc'];
    price = data['price'];
    createdAt = data['createdAt'];
    updatedAt = data['updatedAt'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'category': category,
      'images': images,
      'image': image,
      'desc': desc,
      'price': price,
      'createdAt': createdAt,
      'updatedAt': updatedAt
    };
  }
}
```

========= Product Notifier Lib =============

```
class ProductNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _productList = [];
  Product _currentProduct;

  UnmodifiableListView<Product> get productList =>
      UnmodifiableListView(_productList);

  Product get currentProduct => _currentProduct;

  set productList(List<Product> productList) {
    _productList = productList;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set currentProduct(Product product) {
    _currentProduct = product;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  addProduct(Product product) {
    _productList.insert(0, product);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  deleteProduct(Product product) {
    _productList.removeWhere((_product) => _product.id == product.id);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

========= Get Products API ===============

**There seems to be a problem with the code below. What should I do?**

```
getProducts(ProductNotifier productNotifier) async {
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Products')
      .orderBy("createdAt", descending: true)
      .get();

  List<Product> _productList = [];

  snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
    Product product = Product.fromMap(
        document.data()); 
    _productList.add(product);
  });

  productNotifier.productList = _productList;
}
```

========= Product Feed Page =============

```
class ProductFeed extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductState createState() => _ProductState();
}

class _ProductState extends State<ProductFeed> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    
    ProductNotifier productNotifier =
        Provider.of<ProductNotifier>(context, listen: false);
    getProducts(productNotifier);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AuthNotifier authNotifier = Provider.of<AuthNotifier>(context);
    ProductNotifier productNotifier = Provider.of<ProductNotifier>(context);

    Future<void> _refreshList() async {
     
      getProducts(productNotifier);
    }

   
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Product Feed'       
            ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          // action button
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => signOut(authNotifier),
            child: Text(
              "Logout",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: new RefreshIndicator(
        child: ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: Image.network(
                productNotifier.productList[index].image != null
                    ? productNotifier.productList[index].image
                    : 'https://www.testingxperts.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-img.jpg',
                width: 120,
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              ),
              title: Text(productNotifier.productList[index].name),
              subtitle: Text(productNotifier.productList[index].category),
              onTap: () {
                productNotifier.currentProduct =
                    productNotifier.productList[index];
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Text('Product Detail'); //FoodDetail();
                }));
              },
            );
          },
          itemCount: productNotifier.productList.length,
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
            );
          },
        ),
        onRefresh: _refreshList,
      ),      
    );
  }
}
```

[image: 2]

Comment: can you please show the error that you are getting?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I put a screenshot of the build result above.

Comment: The error is because of your `Firebase Rules` they are restricted. Change them to public for testing purposes only or use `auth` for letting only authenticated users to access your database.

Comment: Agree with the comment above. Could you post your firestore rules as well? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: I modified the permission, but it doesn't get resolved.
Here is an additional error.  ==> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: Fixed an error, problem in a field with nulls in the second data. Thank you.^^